# Is there a way to save the Laravel Component into database and run it later?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to save the Laravel Component into the database and run it later in the Blade along with the HTML tags? For example, lets say the following HTML tags are recorded in the database:

```
<h1>Title Here</h1>
<x-component />
<p>The rest of the HTML tags</p>
```

I know you can render the HTML with {!! $query !!} tag but it's not actually rendering the component.

Thanks.

Comment: And what shall be the purpose of that?

Comment: A better approach would be to make a partial and then include it conditionally.

Comment: Im working on a CMS system which needs 2 part. Pages and Components. They can create a component, which gives them ability to bring that to the Pages they may create later. For example, lets say they create a component called "navigation" containing the link of the pages and later on they any page they create, they can simply add the component to their page by just adding the tag <x-component compid="navigation" /> . I have created the component to retrieve  the data based on the compid value from the database.

Comment: @Donkarnash Would you elaborate more how?

Comment: Do you mean that the users of cms can write custom markup for components and then save to database? Or that you have predefined templates for various components and the users can use the template and fill in their custom data

Comment: This could raise security concerns like Stored XSS. You should avoid storing html code generated by users

Comment: @Donkarnash The user can create content but the fetching the content through component is predefined and filtered by the name it stored with. I have a component which fetches the "Page" and another component to fetch the "Components" content. But I want the "Component" to run within the "Page" when user mentioned it in the "Page" content. Basically they can add <x-component compid="navigation" /> and get the record content with the id of "navigation". I hope Im clear.

Comment: @ml59 What is the best way to store html and run it when its necessary without compromising the security?

Comment: So if the components are pre-defined and the user can add `compid` then why not just store the compid value and based on the compid value include the partial for the component when rendering the page. As such it's a huge vulnerability to accept html content from users and store in database

Comment: To make it safe to store html in database one way is to base64_encode($html) when storing and base64_decode() when getting it out of database - this increases storage requirement significantly - say about 30% or more. `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode` can also used.

Comment: @Donkarnash Well, that is the question. Users create the component content and they should retrive the component content where they want to retrieve it. At the top or bottom, shouldn't matter. That is why I need to have the <x-component /> tag to run where the user is placed it. Also thank you for suggestion on how to store the HTML tag safely.

Comment: @Jay how to avoid xss in this situation it is not an easy task and i might not be the good guy for that . This link might help you https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220447/security-risks-of-user-generated-html

Comment: @ml59 Thank you for the suggestion. I will check it out.